# Web Part not visibile while customizing a page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, sharepoint-addin

This problem is very frustrating...
I am developing a SharePoint hosted add-in.
In this project a I have added a Web Part and code to the `MyWebPart.aspx` file.

When I publish a new version of the add-in (I am in round 34 at the moment) and add it to my test site, sometimes I can customize the home page and add the WebPart to it, sometimes it's not present!

I have not be able to understand the culprit.

In turns I have blamed:

- Some setting in `AppManifest.xml`
- Some unclosed tag in the html code in `MyWebPart.aspx`
- Errors in javascript code in `App.js`

I have not found the crux of the problem, I am suspecting something related to SharePoint online, maybe related to some conflict during Removing/reinstalling the new Add-in version...

Can you give me any clue on where or how to investigare further?
Maybe some sort of log...

***UPDATE***
After some more investigation I have a ***strong suspect*** that the problem is ***random*** and is linked to the App installation phase!

In two (classic) sites I have installed the same app, and in first one the Web Part doesn't appear while on the second one it appears.

So, as new evidence, in the first web site I have disinstalled the App, then reinstalled it... and *voilà* it has appeared!